How can i use offline mode in @angular/fire 17.0.0
I initialize firestore this way in app.module.ts:
    importProvidersFrom([
      provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
      provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
      provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
      fireProvideStorage(() => getStorage()),
    ]),

How do I set the enablePersistence mode?
I tried doing:
 {
      provide: FIRESTORE_SETTINGS,
      useValue: {
        experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
        experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: false,
        useFetchStreams: false,
        enablePersistence: true,
        enableIndexedDbPersistence: true,
        enablePersistentCacheIndexAutoCreation: true,
      },
    },

but it doesn't work :(
